# How do I call an iframe or something similar in PHP?

Tags: php

Hey how do I call an iframe or something similar in PHP?

I have found some code but I might be setting up wrong, this is the code that I found, code:

```
<iframe id="frame" src="load.php?sinput="<?php echo $_GET["sinput"]; ?> > </iframe>
```

Does anybody know any iframe PHP codes or something similar for PHP?

Some people are saying not to use iframes what is there from PHP?

Comment: Your close quote for the `src` attribute should be after the PHP echo.

Comment: You also should escape your input variable for that context, `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: how do you escape the input?

Comment: don't use iframes for local content, there are much better options

Answer (score 1):

There is no function to generate an iframe in PHP.

What you're doing is fine, but allow me to make a suggestion:

```
<?
    $input = "";
    if(isset($_GET['sinput'])) {
        $input = htmlspecialchars($_GET['sinput']);
    }
?>
<iframe id="frame" src="load.php?sinput="<?php echo $input; ?>">Your browser does not support iframes</iframe>
```

EDIT: actually

```
<?
    $url = "load.php";

    // Query Building Logic
    $querys = array();
    if(isset($_GET['sinput'])) {
        $queries[] = "sinput=".htmlspecialchars($_GET['sinput']);
    }

    // Generate full URL
    if(count($queries) > 0) {
        $url .= "?" . implode("&", $queries);
    }
?>
<iframe id="frame" src="<? echo $url; ?>">Your browser does not support iframes</iframe>
```

I think is better quality overall, but ill let that up to my peers to judge. This is just another suggestion, to generate the full usable URL to use in your HTML in a full logic block, rather than relying on information to be present and usable in the template (because if the element `['sinput']` in the `$_GET` array is not set for whatever reason, the page will outright snap on you.

Comment: Although PERSONALLY i don't buy into the whole "dont use short tags" stuff, so preferably i'd do: `<?=$input;?>` to cut down on all the "echo" stuff littered around templates.

Comment: i guess you no better than the authors of php then.

Comment: Zend, the developers of PHP, suggest against using shorttags because it could potentially interfere/get confused with other languages that use similar block descriptors.  You are 150% safe to use shorttags on servers where those rare language blocks could never co-exist.  In fact, in my years as a professional developer, I've yet to come across a single server where that became an issue, ever lol